# How to change Kendo UI grid page index programmatically?

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid, paging

I have a kendo ui grid. Let's say that the JS variable pointing to the grid is called `grid`. How can I go to page 3 programmatically? Thanks.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You might to use:

```
grid.dataSource.query({ page: 3, pageSize: 20 });
```

Documentation in [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-query).

or:

```
grid.dataSource.page(3);
```

Documentation in [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-page)

Comment: grid.pager.page(3) did the trick too, but your answer is correct, thanks for the input, I accept your answer and upvote it too. Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year.

Comment: how to do it with asp mvc helper?

Comment: By this moment - no chance (

Comment: Only the 1st suggestion works upon initial page load.  If the grid has already been loaded I've had success with the second suggestion but not upon initial page load.

Comment: @anyeone, You are right! The question is that `page` does not read data while `query` does.

Comment: I found that this solution throws out the sort on the new page if you had one applied.

I had to resend the sort parameter also:

grid.dataSource.query({ page: 3, pageSize: 20, sort: grid.dataSource.sort() });

Answer (score 10):

```
Answer is just set it pate: 1 when datasource created

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { name: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
    { name: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
    { name: "Ham", category: "Food" }
  ],
  page: 1,
  // a page of data contains two data items
  pageSize: 2
});
```

Comment: Wow! This is so much better than the other answer. Because on initial load it results in one request while the other answer does two requests and flickering.

Comment: Agreed. I used like so: `{ page: sessionStorage.getItem('page'), }`. Setting the page based on the user's session information. It would also be cool to have the grid changed based on queryStrings and such. I would like to emphasize, I have no flicker like @alehro says.

Comment: If you make page change after grid has been already loaded like another answer suggests then grid needs to be redrawn. That is flickering. Though it may not not appear depending on your setup. E. g. if you show grid only after the page change.

Comment: The question was ambiguous, this answer is for setting the *initial* page, however the answer from @OnaBai is for setting the page *dynamically*. Although both answers are correct, this answer does not work in all scenarios.